# Transforming a specific complex function into the form of modulus and argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given a specific complex function: 
\begin{equation}
f(t)=\frac{1}{b+c e^{i t}},
\end{equation}

where $b,c,t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Question: 
I want to express it in terms of the form 
$r+R e^{i \varphi (t)}$ (which is a circle in the complex plane), where $r,R$ are constants **independent of $t$**. Then, how?

My preliminary attempt shows that

\begin{equation}
f(t)=\frac{b+c e^{i \varphi (t)}}{b^2-c^2};
\end{equation}

however, the phase function $\varphi (t)$ seems to be complicated and so-far no analytic expression is obtained.
So, can anyone obtain an analytic expression for $\varphi (t)$?

Comment: I think what Cesaro described in his answer is the best you can do. The form you want describes a circle as you said yourself but your function $f$ does not describe a circle in the complex plane so you can't represent it as one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\frac{1}{b+c e^{it}} = \frac{b+c e^{-it}}{(b+c e^{it})(b+c e^{-it})}
$$

so we have

$$
\cases{
x = \frac{b}{b^2+2 b c \cos (t)+c^2}+\frac{c \cos (t)}{b^2+2 b c \cos (t)+c^2}\\
y = -\frac{c \sin (t)}{b^2+2 b c \cos (t)+c^2}
}
$$

now solving for $\sin(t),\cos(t)$ we have

$$
\cases{
\sin(t) = \frac{y (b-c) (b+c)}{c-2 b c x}\\
\cos(t) = \frac{b-x \left(b^2+c^2\right)}{c (2 b x-1)}
}
$$

and then

$$
\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t) = 1
$$

after that from the real plane $(x,y)$ to the complex plane is easy.

Comment: No, you don't understand my question. I required that the form should be +*exp[()], where , are constants independent of . Everyone in the first response comes with your idea. But that is not what I what.

Comment: Some more steps attached.